# Trigger Updating another table - Baseball Database

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is my first time writing T-SQL so I'd like to get some criticism on how I wrote this trigger.

I'm building a Pitch-Tracking App that will use a relational database to track Pitches, At-Bats, Games, etc. Everything starts with tracking the individual Pitch in an individual AB, so I figured whenever `tbl_PitchLog` is updated, it would update that individual At Bat ID in the `tbl_AtBats` table. Let me know if I'm straying or if I'm on some semblance of a straight path to elegant T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_PitchLog]
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [At_Bat_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [Batter_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [Pitcher_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [Game_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [Season_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [Pitch_Type] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Pitch_Speed] BIGINT NULL, 
    [Pitch_X] BIGINT NULL, 
    [Pitch_Y] BIGINT NULL, 
    [Strike] BIT NULL, 
    [Swung] BIT NULL, 
    [Contact] BIT NULL, 
    [Fair] BIT NULL, 
    [R] BIT NULL,
    [H] BIT NULL,
    [1B] BIT NULL, 
    [2B] BIT NULL, 
    [3B] BIT NULL, 
    [HR] BIT NULL, 
    [RBI] INT NULL, 
    [BB] BIT NULL, 
    [SO] BIT NULL, 
    [IBB] BIT NULL, 
    [HBP] BIT NULL, 
    [SH] BIT NULL, 
    [SF] BIT NULL, 
    [GIDP] BIT NULL 
)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_PitchLog]
    ON [dbo].[tbl_PitchLog]
    FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    DECLARE @Strikes integer, @Balls integer
    DECLARE @Fouls integer
    DECLARE @Contact integer
    IF Strike = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @Strikes = 1;
        SET @Balls = 0;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Strikes = 0;
        SET @Balls = 1;
    END
    IF Fair = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Fouls = 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Fouls = 0;
    END
    IF Contact = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Contact = 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Contact = 0;
    END
    BEGIN
        SET NoCount ON
        UPDATE tbl_AtBats
        SET tbl_AtBats.PitchCount = tbl_AtBats.PitchCount + 1,
        tbl_AtBats.Strikes = tbl_AtBats.Strikes + @Strikes, 
        tbl_AtBats.Balls = tbl_AtBats.Balls + @Balls,
        tbl_AtBats.Fouls = tbl_AtBats.Fouls + @Fouls, 
        tbl_AtBats.Contact = tbl_AtBats.Contact + @Contact,
        tbl_AtBats.Swings = tbl_AtBats.Swings + inserted.Swung,
        tbl_AtBats.R = inserted.R,
        tbl_AtBats.H = inserted.H,
        tbl_AtBats.[1B] = inserted.[1B],
        tbl_AtBats.[2B] = inserted.[2B],
        tbl_AtBats.[3B] = inserted.[3B],
        tbl_AtBats.HR = inserted.HR,
        tbl_AtBats.RBI = inserted.RBI,
        tbl_AtBats.BB = inserted.BB,
        tbl_AtBats.SO = inserted.SO,
        tbl_AtBats.IBB = inserted.IBB,
        tbl_AtBats.HBP = inserted.HBP,
        tbl_AtBats.SH = inserted.SH,
        tbl_AtBats.SF = inserted.SF,
        tbl_AtBats.GIDP = inserted.GIDP
        WHERE tbl_AtBats.Id = inserted.At_Bat_ID;
    END
```

Comment: Not sure you need bigint here.

Comment: @paparazzo, I know it has been a bit of time, but could you expand on your thought about the `BIGINT`s?

Answer (score 1):

at first glance I found a couple of things that might give you issues

> ```
> IF Strike = 1
> BEGIN
>     SET @Strikes = 1;
>     SET @Balls = 0;
> END
> ELSE
> BEGIN
>     SET @Strikes = 0;
>     SET @Balls = 1;
> END
> ```

IIRC, you can perform 4 foul hits before you are considered "out", and that a foul hit on the first and second pitch are also counted as "Strikes" but not the third foul hit. going through this logic will give you a false "ball" count because it is a foul but not a strike.

---

I also noticed

> ```
> IF Contact = 0
> BEGIN
>     SET @Contact = 1;
> END
> ELSE
> BEGIN
>     SET @Contact = 0;
> END
> ```

I assumed that `@Contact` was your "hits" but I tried to go through the logic and I am a bit confused.  If `Contact = 0` means to me that there wasn't a hit, but you set the variable to true (`SET @Contact = 1;`)

Again IIRC, not every contact with the ball counts as a "hit"

Comment: It looks like I misstyped that Contact part. Basically any time the batter makes contact with the ball is "contact", and in Baseball, you can foul off any number of pitches. So A foul and a fair ball would be considered contact. But it looks like I need to change that `IF` to be `IF Contact = 1`

Comment: maybe the 4 Fouls and your out was a trick to keep games from getting too long in Tee-ball or Little League...lol  I have always thought it was 4 fouls and your out, thanks for the info @jDave1984